# How do I pass a string array from a function to main

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I'm trying to Initialize a string in **Initialize** then pass it to **int main()** for screen output, but it seems that the strings that are initialized have become corrupted.

**Headers**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

**Initialize**

```
void
Initialize(char* STRINGs)
{
    STRINGs = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
    STRINGs = "hello" ;

    printf("1: %s\n",STRING);
}
```

**Main**

```
int
main (char* STRINGs)
{
    Initialize(STRINGs);

//The program stops working when it reaches this section
    printf("2: %s",STRINGs);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to learn strcpy and lot of string operations, pointers before malloc.

Comment: The program starts from `main` function. So you should do the task you want in `main` by using another function.

Comment: This `int
main (char* STRINGs)` is not valid C. Either use `int
main (void)` or `int
main (int argc, char * argv[])` or `int
main (int argc, char ** argv)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
void Initialize(char** STRING)
```

Instead:

```
void Initialize(char* STRINGs)
```

because you want to change the the address to which STRING points

Also you have wrong prototype of `main`

Try:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void Initialize(char** STRING)
{
    *STRING = malloc(6);
    strcpy(*STRING, "hello");

    printf("1: %s\n",*STRING);
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* STRING;

    Initialize(&STRING);

    printf("2: %s\n",STRING);

    free(STRING);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it worked! thank you

Comment: The fact that it can work does not necessarily mean that it's a good solution.  It's usually better to avoid pointer to pointer unless you have to - in this case you certainly don't

Answer (score 3):

First, you have wrong prototype for `int main (char* STRINGs)`, which must be either:

- `int main()`, or
- `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

> How do I pass a string array from a function to main

As it stands, you can create a string inside your `Initialize()` then return a pointer to that string.

There are several issues in your `Initialize()` though.

Here's a suggestion to change:

```
char * 
Initialize()
{
    char *STRINGs = malloc(strlen("hello") + 1);  // <-- malloc must include an additional space for the NULL terminator.
    strcpy( STRINGs, "hello" );  // <-- NEVER use assignment for string type.
    printf("1: %s\n",STRINGs);
    return STRINGs;
}
```

Then your `main()` can be like this:

```
int main()
{
    char *str = Initialize();
    printf( "str = %s\n", str );
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: do not forget to add `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Why `sizeof(char)* (strlen("hello") + 1)`?  As `sizeof(char)` is always 1, code could use `strlen("hello") + 1` or if trying got account for the size of the type, use `sizeof *STRINGs * (strlen("hello") + 1)`.

Comment: @chux `sizeof( char )`  (instead of `1`) is preferred to make it explict. But I see this case it looks a bit cumbersome. I'm editing the code based on your comment - thanks.

Comment: `char * 
Initialize()` should be `char * 
Initialize(void)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code to initialize the string variable

```
  char * Initialize()
  {
    char* STRINGs="HELLO";

     printf("1: %s\n",STRINGs);

     return STRINGs;
  }

int main ()
{

 char *strings =Initialize();

 //The program stops working when it reaches this section
 printf("2: %s",strings);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char * 
Initialize()` should be `char * 
Initialize(void)`.

Comment: An explanation why this works would suite the answer well. As it stands it does not help very much.

Comment: Look at the question he asked . He want to initialize a variable to a string in a function. so according to the questions requirement my ans may satisfy the question.

Comment: and plz explain why it should be `char * Initialize(void)` and not `char * Initialize()`

Comment: Please see the current C-Standard on this. From the C11 Standard (draft) 6.11.7 (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.7): "*The use of function definitions with separate parameter identifier and declaration lists
(not prototype-format parameter type and identifier declarators) is an obsolescent feature.*"

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer. First, when allocating memory for any variable, it must be freed or you'll get some nasty system errors at some point or at the very least, a memory leak.

In the int main(), the declaration should ideally be `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`.

I also recommend allocating at least one more byte of memory just in case you create a string and a function you use later on requires a null character appended to it.

I fixed your code to make it work at its bare minimum.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* Initialize(){
  char* string = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
  strcpy(string,"hello");
  printf("1: %s\n",string);
  return string;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
  char *strings=Initialize();
  printf("2: %s\n",strings);
  free(strings);
  return 0;
}
```

For a shorter version of your code, I suggest this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
  char* strings=malloc(6);
  strcpy(string,"hello");
  printf("2: %s\n",strings);
  free(strings);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char * 
Initialize()` should be `char * 
Initialize(void)`.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of understanding, let us suppose `STRINGs` of `main` function is `a`.

And `STRINGs` of `initialize` function is `b`.

At first, in main `a` is pointing to some unknown location say `u`. When you pass this to the `initialize` function then `b` also starts pointing to the location `u`.

But, after the allocation of memory, `b` starts pointing to some other memory that was allocated by `malloc` say `m`.

Now you change the contents of memory `m` by use of `b`. But `a` is still pointing to the unknown location `u`.

So both the pointers are now pointing towards two different memory locations. So when you print contents where `b` is pointing it works perfectly and then you `printf` contents of `a` which has no specific location or may be `null`.

So, because of this your problem came.

And also, there is another error in your program that is in the `printf` of `initialize` function, it has given a parameter `STRING` which is undeclared....make it `STRINGs`.

Hope you will like the explanation. Its a little bit tricky.

Thanks :-)

Comment: oh, I though void functions share variables with main and malloc simply expands the memory. this will clear some misconceptions. thank you

Comment: Nicely explained. However "*`null`*" should read "*`NULL`*", as `null` is something different.